# Use Samsung-type page swipe animation without installing launcher

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, launcher, htc

I'm a new convert from iOS to Android.

I really like the Samsung type animations when you swipe left or right from one home screen to another (i.e. the 3D box rotate). But I don't have a Samsung, and was wondering if there was an app I can use to do that on my device without installing a launcher. I really like my phone's look so I don't want to use a launcher.

Comment: You're already using a launcher (the pre-installed one, probably) -- and a launcher is, basically, nothing but another app, so it would fit your description. Apart from that I agree with geffchang: as transition effects are done by the launcher, there's no other way to obtain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find a launcher similar to the stock one. You should know that the launcher only changes the look of the homescreens and app drawer. They can also be customized pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to be possible. AFAIK, transition effects are tied to the launcher.